# accessing controller $scope in filter not defined on controller

Tags: angularjs

Inside  an ng-repeat, I wish to format the date on the fly as the user has the option to change the formatting, so I created a filter like this

```
<ul>
<li ng-repeat"item in items">
      <h2>{{item.date | formatDate }} </h2>

</li>
</ul>
```

And then in my code

```
 myapp.filter('formatDate', function(){
   return function(date) {
     return formatDateFunction(date)
   }
  }

  function formatDateFunction(unix_epoch){

   var date = new Date(unix_epoch);     
   var language = $scope.desiredLanguage
   var time = date.toLocaleTimeString(language, options);
   return time;
  }

   myapp.controller('MyCtrl',[$scope,
        function MyCtrl($scope){
            $scope.desiredLanguage = 'en-us';
            --code omitted
```

The problem is that the filter calls a function that requires a value defined on the $scope of the controller so the way that I've currently written the code that value is not available i.e. $scope is not available in the `format` filter, nor the `formatDateFunction` that it calls.

Question: how can I access the scope in the filter above, or, conversely, arrange it so that `<h2>{{item.date | formatDate }} </h2>` calls a filter on the controller?

Comment: try using this.desiredLanguage inside formatDateFunction function

Comment: @JorgeCasariego doesn't work.  `this` in the formateDateFunction is 'undefined`' There is no connection between the formatDateFunction` and the `MyCtrl` where the `$scope.desiredLanguage` is defined, i.e. $scope doesn't exist in the formatDateFunction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've mixed your separation of concerns, you should be providing the desired language as a parameter to your filter.  This means that you would still define desiredLanguage in the controller as a scope variable a la

```
$scope.desiredLanguage = 'en-us'
```

but you would pass it to your filter as a parameter through the HTML. This means that your controller stays the same, and  your filter becomes:

```
myapp.filter('formatDate', function(){
     return function(date,language) {
           return formatDateFunction(date,language)
     }
}
function formatDateFunction(unix_epoch, language){
     var date = new Date(unix_epoch);     
     var time = date.toLocaleTimeString(language, options);
     return time;
}
```

Then in your html you can just use:

```
<h2>{{item.date | formatDate:desiredLanguage }} </h2>
```

This keeps the separation of scope and parameters in your control, which encourages reuse, modularity, and testability.

Comment: ok thank you I figured it out with you help but since the gist of the question was how to pass the scope to the filter, it might be clearer to anyone else reading this question that in `formatDate:desiredLanguage` the parameter `desiredLanguage` is defined in the controller on $scope, like `$scope.desiredLanguage` so that the scope is passed into the filter.

Comment: Updated to reflect your suggestions, as you're right it could be clearer.